# Hiding UITableViewCell separator for individual cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I require a UITableViewCell separator for the majority of my cells, but some of them should be hidden.

The way this is set is `self.tableView.separatorStyle`, which would apply to every cell.

A heavy-handed work around is to disable it, and then draw it onto cells manually as a UIView, but I don't want to go there.

How can I otherwise remove the separator for individual cells?

Comment: I guess you have to draw your own separator in every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have custom cell and add separator in this cell, this way you can manage your cell separator. Or you can `addSubView` a `UIView` for separator to your cell like **iPatel's** answer, but be careful for memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different `ReUseIdentifier` for the cells which you don need `separatorStyle`.Don draw anything onto this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom view as a separator is a lot of work. Besides adding a property, setting constraints, etc, you need to worry about matching the color and line width of the default separators (`1.0 / view.window.screen.scale` so it's one pixel tall, not one point).

It's way easier to use the default separator view, and hide it by setting the insets. For example, turn on separators for the table, then in your `UITableViewCell` subclass do something like this:

```
var showsSeperator: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        let leftInset: CGFloat
        if showsSeperator {
            leftInset = layoutMargins.left
        } else {
            leftInset = 1000  // Out of site.
        }
        separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will **not only** effect the separator view's inset but also the insets of the default labels (such as `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel`, etc.)